# VBA: Create and array once, call multiple times in Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a question regarding holding an array in an open workbook to be called.

I have a large array which is created on running a macro, and it takes approximately 10s to run start to finish (not prohibitive, but inconvenient enough).

I'd like to be able to create the array once, then use a change in a worksheet to update the data displayed from it.

For example: I have multiple customers stored in the first dimension of the array, then more detailed information about them in the deeper levels. I am hoping to use a user input change to cell A1 (putting in a new Customer ID) to call a different set of values from the array - and display.

I've done this before running a macro to create the entire array before - but this time I want to avoid the 'create array' process, and just have it stored in the sheet.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are **2** typical ways:

1. store the array values in a block of cells somewhere in the workbook
2. `Dim` the array **above** the subs in the Module *(this will make it somewhat permanent)*

See:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Scope.aspx

Answer (score 0):

to make an array global (accessible from all workbook),
Declare it in a module, before any sub\function :

```
Option explicit

Public Arr() as string 'for example


Sub firstsub()
....
End sub
```

Also , to make the scope of the array smaller, you could declare it as private in your worksheet's code. But this would be more tricky to implement, because of the 10s macro who needs to interact with the array.